# VIM create column of REPEATING increasing numbers

Tags: vim

How can I create a column like this one?

```
15
15
15
16
16
16
17
17
17
```

I know (from this site) how to make a column of increasing numbers:

```
:1,10s/^/\=line('.')/g
```

how to multiply them by 3 or even how to increase all the numbers by 5:

```
:1,10s/^/\=line('.')*3+5/g
```

But how can I use integer division here?

Comment: Not sure what you are exactly asking, but to use division (`/`) inside that substitution, just use a different substitution separator. For example: `1,10s:^:\=line('.')*3+5/2:g`

Comment: Perfect! This is what I wanted, thank you!!!

Comment: Oh, and what I found [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Making_a_list_of_numbers)

`:for i in range(3,11) | put =i/3+14 | endfor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with macro too, so that make it independent on line number.

here is the quick and dirty way:

Assume you have an empty buffer, press `i` and type a random number say:`72`, then you press:

`qqY3pG<c-a>q`

and press `x@q` you will see `x+1` blocks were generated, but the last line you don't need, just `dd` to remove.

something like:

```
72
72
72
73
73
73
74
74
74
```

Comment: Empty buffers are easy to make. When I do self referencing macros or plan on appending to a register I will often do this trick: `q<register>q` and for connivance `qqq` and use the `"q` register. This trick reads: start macro recording and use register `<register>` (or in example above `q`) then immediately stop recording.

Comment: For reference `qqY3pG<c-a>q` will expand to: start recording macro into register `q`; yank the current line into register `"`; paste register `"` three times below current cursor; move cursor to the bottom of the file; increment by one the number under or immediately to the right of the cursor; stop recording macro.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in a multi-step process:

1. Create a single repeating sequence (without duplicates) using the new-ish [<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>CTRL+A</kbd> command](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#v_g_CTRL-A).
2. Copy the text and past as many times as desired duplicates.
3. Use `:sort n` on the full set of lines to get the desired list with duplicates.